# Finding list of prime numbers

Tags: haskell

I want to find a list of prime numbers, given a range of integers -- compute all primes in said range:

```
primesR :: Integral a => a -> a -> [a]
primesR a b | even a = filter isPrime [a+1,a+3..b-1]
            | True   = filter isPrime [a,a+2..b]
```

It seems intuitive to filter out through the odd part of the list and then the remainder but I am not getting a correct result..How could I change this code to run properly?

Comment: Can you give an example of how this function is not working as expected?

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution is:

```
primesR :: Integral a => a -> a -> [a]
primesR a b | even a = filter isPrime [a+1,a+3..b]
            | True   = filter isPrime [a,a+2..b]
```

You mistakenly had `even a = filter isPrime [a+1,a+3..b-1]`. That is incorrect. You need to iterate all the way to the end of the list.